# Final decimal digit of $1!+2!+3!+...+10!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do you find the final decimal digit of $1!+2!+3!+...+10!$?

Any hints would be helpful. Expanding this is too tedious, and I think it has something to do with congruence or prime numbers.

Comment: HInt: what is the final digit of any number that has 10 as a factor?

Comment: All factorial terms $5!$ and above may be discarded, as they all end with the digit $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1+2+6+4+0+0+0+0+0+0 mod 10 =3 mod 10